# Synchronize Rails with a duplicated database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, ruby-on-rails-4

A little bit stumped here, can't seem to find anyone with the question. I feel like my question is a lot simpler than it probably sounds. Basically I want to have an exact copy of my rails database on a different server, as it is being populated. Let me explain with an example

I have a production website that needs to be up at all times is the bottom line here.

Currently if the website goes down, I have to use the latest copy that I have of the database (Because the server is down), and when the site comes back up, I have to manually import anything new into the original mysql server. So I am looking for a way to keep the mysql server on both servers in sync with each other so that if one goes down, they both still have the same information.

I understand that this can add a lot of overhead in the rails app, which I am  not that concerned about as I can find ways to defer the mysql queries. Unless someone knows a better way to do this?

Comment: Where are you hosting

Comment: I am using a dedicated server, so I can do anything with it. @MZaragoza